# Finding Raspbian iterative loop unreliable - how to report?

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, failure

I have developed multiple YouTube Raspberry PI clock projects since 2014 and all of them require iterative loops checking for the time (seconds) to change to update a digital, binary or roman numeral displays.  With the latest Python 3.5.3 and Raspbian (NOPS 2.8.2) operating system, the iterative loop is no longer reliable.  The same problem occurs on PI Zero-WIFI, 3B, and A+ platforms, but not PC.

I wrote a simple iterative program (listed below) that checks for the change in time (seconds), counts the number of loop iterations between seconds, and watches for intervals when there have been no iterations.  No iterations indicate that Python is getting ready to completely hang and the mouse will become unreliable, later it will quit driving the HDMI display.  I collected data the first time a zero-iteration count was detected between seconds.
I average number of iterations and seconds of proper operation on each platform is as follows:

```
PLATFORM -- AVERAGE ITERATIONS/SECOND -- AVERAGE SECONDS TO FAILURE -- SAMPLES
MODEL A+ --           4,995           --          27,569            --   10
ZERO WIFI--           8,384           --          94,288            --   10
MODEL 3B --          47,199           --         208,571            --   10 
PC (I5)  --       1,000,000           --   DID NOT FAIL IN 12 DAYS  --    1
```

I tried using different power supplies, avoiding use of an external USB hub, and disconnecting WIFI from A+ without making any difference. Insured all platforms were using the current Raspbian downloaded from the website on 11/07/2018. No overclocking options were added.

I have pictures of the screen and unit being used at the time of failure.

```
# OPSYS-BUG# 11/02/18 Jim Roberts
# Import system subroutines.
from time import sleep         
import time

# CONSTANTS
lastsec=''                      # LAST SECOND PROCESSED
ct=1                            # LOOP COUNTS BETWEEN LCD REFRESH
ctot=0
cnbr=0
csec=0
mx=10
try:                            # ESTABLISH ERROR HANDLING FOR CTRL+C
    while mx>0:
        s=int(time.localtime().tm_sec)          # SECONDS
        if s != lastsec:
            lastsec=s    
            h=time.localtime().tm_hour          # HOURS
            m=time.localtime().tm_min           # MINUTES
            out=str(h+100)[1:3]+':'+str(m+100)[1:3]+':'+str(s+100)[1:3]  
            ctc=str(ct)         
            if ct < 10000:
                ctc = " " + ctc
            csec=csec+1    
            print(ctc + "   " + out+"   "+str(csec)+"   "+str(csec/(60*60*24)))
            cnbr=cnbr+1
            ctot=ctot+ct
            if ct==0:           # ERROR OCCURING - STOP AFTER MX OCCURENCES
                mx=mx-1     
                print("LOOPS- ", ctot, "COUNTS- ", cnbr, "AVG- ", ctot/cnbr)
                print("CYCLES             SINCE--START")       
                print("PER-SEC HH:MM:SS   SECS    DAYS") 
            ct=0
        else:
            ct=ct+1                 # BUMP LOOP CYCLE BETWEEN LCD REFRESHES
except KeyboardInterrupt:        
    GPIO.cleanup()                  # IF CTRL+C ENTERED, CLEAN UP AND EXIT
```

Comment: Please place your code in a code block.

Comment: What else have you got running on your Pi's? In my experience Pi's usually start hanging when memory is low or being swapped to disk - which might suggest why the A+/Zero fail earlier.

Comment: I have not consciously started any other tasks than the normal opening window, I started a Python window, then selected my test code and pressed RUN.  Nothing else was started.

Comment: Before I developed the test program, all three platforms would totally cease to even paint the HDMI terminal, the mouse was unresponsive or extremely slow (if the screen was still visible).  The program senses the platform is about ready to seize and ten detections of the error.  When the program seizes, all platforms have very sluggish or no response or no HDMI screen status.  Will be glad to all the SLEEP logic, but fear it is something deeper.

Comment: This is not a Pi specific question. Tight loops like this are poor practice. Linux includes utilities that efficiently execute code at intervals e.g `watch -n 1 date` will display time every second. You could replace `date` with a program which displays on your clock.

Comment: @JTRoberts, can you elaborate on 'fear it is something deeper'. Raspbian is compiled from mainstream Debian so this would be an issue to be found on many many Debian or, if so deep as to be a kernel problem, most Linux systems. Even when specifically tuned to be more responsive to code like this, Linux is still not a real-time operating system and would struggle to do it's housekeeping in the face of a code loop like this. Additionally, as a Pi doesn't have many supporting co-processors, it has more work to do and its mass storage will hold it up if it has some catchup to do.

Comment: I have written clean up code that interrupted regular processing.  I understand such code may stop processing of the primary task (Python), perform cleanup, and then restore everything to continue.   But when my Python program exits, the health of the operating system should not be jeopardized.  I programmed interrupt tape controller code running four reel to reel copies to max out the CPU and test my cleanup routines, then verified the copies.    These Pi platforms are unusable (unable to start another task) when my Python program exits cleanly.  The cleanup routines are problematic.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no delay / sleep in the code, you are hitting the CPU & the underlying Linux systems pretty hard - I'd imagine that at some point some housekeeping is being triggered and I've seen SD Card writes tie up a Pi for a second or two.

Can you put a `sleep(0.01)` at the bottom of your while loop - this will reduce accuracy / response time by a 100th of a second but you can tune it accordingly.

Doing this reduces the CPU load on my iMac from ~95% to 1%.

I'm offering this as a pragmatic solution to test - the underlying details of what exactly is going on seems a bit academic - a loop to check the time for the next second to update a clock display running at a rate of 100 per second seems appropriate.

Comment: This was about to be my answer too - i don't like CPU intensive loops. On my Pi3B+ adding time.sleep(0.01) reduces overall CPU from approx 25% to approx 1% (presumably 1 core).

Comment: 25% in top or similar is a core - in my answer the ~95% refers to a single core as Activity Monitor is happy to tell you that a process is using 533% which can be rather confusing!

Comment: While I admit the program is a bit academic (developed for a high school class), after the program defects ten faults (no loop iterations occurring during during an elapsed second) it exits.  The program is no longer active, yet all three platforms are no longer dependable.  The mouse is extreme slow (if at all), mouse depresses are usually ignored, and sometimes the HDMI monitor is no longer painted.  While I agree there are needs for house keeping, those routines should not leave the platform in a unreliable state after the program exits.

Comment: Anything that takes a hammering is going to take time to recover but with many other things, we wouldn't give it a hammering in the first place due to the consequent negative consequences. A loop such as this is not demonstrating good programming practise under any circumstances. If you want some other commands with negative outcomes, try 'sudo rm -rf /*' - just because you can type it, means to say you should.

Comment: 1) First, I grant tight loop if not great coding, but you have to start somewhere.  Putting that aside. 2) I have been working on this code for educational purposes for several years.  It used to not cause the operating system to crash, it does now.  3) Operating systems are built to recover from some of the worst programmers. 4) If a program ends, there should not be permanent impairment to the operating system being able to start someone thing else.  5) How to I escalate this to someone who needs to be aware of such a problem. It will affect others interested in industrial use dependability.

Comment: @Nick McCloud - As suggested, I added a SLEEP(0.01) statement within the loop.  The program ended after 1.12 DAYS (about average on a ZERO) counting 88 iterations/second.  While the mouse was responsive, I tried to re-RUN, the program without rebooting.  It would accept depressing RUN, but not never started execution display.  I am running this in the Raspbian window-like environment.  I have a picture of the screen to share if I have an email address.  The program does nothing fancy.  Two years ago it would run for weeks, but something has changed since then.  My SD memory is 8G.

Comment: @Nick McCloud - As suggested, ran program with SLEEP(0.01) statement again.  The program ended after 1.11 days counting 87.5 iterations/second. Like the previous time, the mouse can activate the RUN drop-down and can select the RUN option, but execution never commences in the shell window.  While I can "X" out of the Python program window and it exits, selecting "X" in upper right corner of the Python 3.5.3 Shell window - it does not respond until a few minutes later.  Then was able to restart the shell window though a little sluggish, open and restart the program.  JTRoberts